# I have fixed it but when I select any activity in from navbar drawer it is not showing that activity

Tags: android

My code:

```
public class proclass extends AppCompatActivity {
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
  String url = "";
  ProgressDialog pd;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_master);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, content, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrong code in your `onCreate()`, it should be:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

  ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_master);
}
```

Comment: it is showing only navigation bar not the activity that means activity is the same